# how can i shuffle the lines of a file by chunks of 100 lines with Unix command line tools?

Tags: unix, shuffle

I have a large text file and I want to shuffle the file by chunks of 100 lines. So the order within each chunk of 100 lines is preserved. Is there anyway to accomplish this with only Unix command line tools?

Comment: i can't come up any idea about how to preserve any number of 100 lines in pure bash. what about perl or python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  First `split` the input file into 100-line chunks named "foo...".  Then ask `shuf` to permute their names.  Then `cat` the results together.

```
split -l 100 INPUTFILE foo
cat $(/bin/ls foo* | shuf)
```

You can test this out briefly by creating an input file of the numbers 1 to 100 like so:

```
seq 1 100 > inputfile.txt
```

and then using chunks of, say, 5 lines.